# Why is the H2 client not working with the node's H2 database?

Tags: corda

I am using the latest [H2 client](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) to connect to my node's H2 database. However on connecting the client is unable to display the table names in the left panel and gives the following error.

```
Column "COLUMN_TYPE" not found; SQL statement: SELECT COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND TABLE_NAME = ? [42122-198] 42S22/42122
```

My node is running a version 3.3-corda jar. Further, if I run a simple query to view one of the tables, the client simply states that the connection is lost. I have confirmed my nodes are still running. Could you please advise on how to address this or if there are any workarounds?

Comment: Is this a standalone corda node or one started using the node driver for testing purposes? We always had to stop the node driver nodes to connect to the databases.

Comment: My nodes are run as a deployment set up using a gradle task - not with the node driver - so it's a standalone node.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are able to log into the database via the H2 client. The missing table might be result of bugs on implementing the schema.

Feel free to take a look at our samples of how to implement the schemas for querableStates:

Java version: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Features/queryablestate-carinsurance/contracts/src/main/java/net/corda/examples/carinsurance/schema

Kotlin version: https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/master/Features/queryableState-carinsurance/contracts/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/samples/schema/InsuranceSchemaV1.kt